# JSONParse array nested inside of callback lost the context

Tags: javascript, json

I'm try to parse a object from response to web service, that has the following structure:

```js
{ "idRonda":"1",
  "puntos":{
             "p1":{"id":1,"descripcion":"punto uno","tag":"0497e1b13e0280"},
             "p2":{"id":2,"descripcion":"punto dos","tag":"0498e9b13e0280"},
             "p4":{"id":4,"descripcion":"punto cuatro","tag":"04419092432f80"},
             "p5":{"id":5,"descripcion":"punto cinco","tag":"0462f812b82a80"},
             "p3":{"id":3,"descripcion":"punto tres","tag":"046cfd92432f80"}
           }
}
```

So, I try to iterate over the "array" puntos, then I do the following:

```js
//data has the response from web service
var json = JSON.parse(data);
var puntos = json.puntos; //until here it's ok
```

When I print the value and type of puntos :

```js
console.log( " Puntos Object : "+ puntos );
console.log( " TypeOf : "+ Ember.typeOf(puntos) );
```

Output:

```
Puntos Object : [object Object]
TypeOf : string
```

My attempt:

```js
for (var k in puntos)
{
    // I thought that k must be "p1", "p2"..., but I'm wrong 
    if (puntos.hasOwnProperty(k))
    {  
        var values = puntos[k];
        var id = values['id'];
    }
}
```

If I print the k value I get(I don't know what mean it):

```
key: 0
key: 1
.
.
.
key: 13
key: 14
key: fmt
key: w
key: loc
key: camelize
key: decamelize
key: dasherize
key: underscore
key: classify
key: capitalize
key: htmlSafe
```

Now how iterate over the puntos object to get `id`, `descripcion` and `tag` values?

**UPDATE:**

```js
 var puntos = json.puntos;      
 var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Rondas", "1.0", "Dev", -1);
 db.transaction(function(tx)
 {

        tx.executeSql("SELECT * from Punto;", [], function(tx, res) 
        {
            if( res.rows.length === 0)
            {
                for (var k in puntos)
                {

                    if (puntos.hasOwnProperty(k))
                    {
                        var id = puntos[k].id;
                        var descripcion = puntos[k].descripcion;
                        var tag = puntos[k].tag;
                        console.log( "KEY: "+k+" ,ID: "+id + " ,DESCRIPCIÓN: "+descripcion+" ,TAG: "+tag );
                    }

                }
            }
        }
 }
```

The code above fail becase the object `puntos` lost the scope because it inside of a callback then then only solution is ensure the object context.

**SOLUTION**

```js
    db.transaction(function(tx)
    {
        //ensure the object context.
        var points = puntos;
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * from Punto;", [], function(tx, res) 
        {
            if( res.rows.length === 0)
            {
                for (var k in points)
                {
                   ...
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `for (var k in puntos)` k is the "p1" , "p2" , "p3" ... try to print the data as a string before you parse it to see where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop like this

```
for(key in puntos)
{
   var id = puntos[key].id;
   var descripcion= puntos[key].descripcion;
   var tag = puntos[key].tag;
}
```

Comment: Nice except you spelled description differently than in the original code.

Comment: @SteveWellens Thank you ! I updated it

Comment: Thanks @Khalid, but not works, I get `undefined` for all values.

Comment: @CristianChaparroA. it works fine for me, and the loop you posted on your question also worked fine for me ... I don't know where is the problem